# Java Gradle code explanation findlookupvalues

Tags: java, spring, gradle, hql

I am trying to understand a code created by other, as below

```
List<ScheduleParameter> scheduleParamList =  daoService.findLookupValues(ScheduleParameter.class, "active", true);
```

Through this code its calling a function from below

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(value = "manager", readOnly = true)
public <T extends LookupValueBean> List<T> findLookupValues(Class<T> lookupClass, String lookupFilterAttr, boolean lookupFilterValue){  
    log.info("DaoService Class - findLookupValues()");
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(lookupClass).add(Restrictions.eq(lookupFilterAttr, lookupFilterValue)).list();                 
  }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(value = "manager", readOnly = true)
public <T extends LookupValueBean> T findLookupValues(Class<T> lookupClass, String lookupFilterAttr, String lookupFilterValue){
    log.info("DaoService Class - findLookupValues()");
    return  (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(lookupClass).add(Restrictions.eq(lookupFilterAttr, lookupFilterValue).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();                   
}
```

This funtionality is used to get data from the database, but when I print the result in log i get 0, can you explain if the code is wrong or something I am missing.

```
log.info("schedule parameter list "+scheduleParamList.size());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the the error, the bean class were not mapped, and that's the reason it was not getting data from database.